Formica Laminate for Shower Surround
Has anyone used a laminate sheet (Formica) applied to CDX (low-grade plywood) as a shower surround?
In theory I think it would work if it has no joints and is well-sealed at the corners and along shower basin. It is also very cost effective.

A fast search does mention the seams are the problem with water.  Otherwise if you like it and make sure all seams are sealed well, it should work.  It will probably require more TLC than formica on 1/2 or 3/4 inch wood.
